# KeyError: 'user_name'

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to run tests inside a container but all the tests I run return an error `E               KeyError: 'user_name'`

The test:

```
args = (<api.views.Connector object at 0x7f5c66288d30>,)
kwargs = {'connector': 'googleanalytics', 'user_info': {'active': True, 'adwords_account': None, 'adwords_include_productgroup_data': None, 'adwords_medium_value': None, ...}}
start_time = 1676136763.008559, error_response = <Response 27 bytes [400 BAD REQUEST]>, api_key = '2ee6af7ff92f753363d420fc4a2b1233f136'
auth_token = None
users = [{'active': True, 'adwords_account': None, 'adwords_include_productgroup_data': None, 'adwords_medium_value': None, ...}]

    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()

        error_response = jsonify({"error": "Not authorized"})
        error_response.status_code = 400

        # Check if the user is authenticating with an api_key
        api_key = request.values.get("api_key")
        auth_token = request.values.get("access_token")

        if api_key:
            logger.info(
                "OAuth validation requesting for api_key=%s : %s s",
                api_key,
                time.time() - start_time,
            )

            users = api_helpers.get_users_db_info({"user.api_key": f"$eq.{api_key}"})

            logger.info(
                "OAuth validation returned data for api_key=%s : %s s",
                api_key,
                time.time() - start_time,
            )

            # If the user was found with the expected key
            # set the `user` parameter and run the connector
            if len(users) > 0:
                kwargs["user_info"] = users[0]

                logger.info(
                    "OAuth validation time for api_key=%s user_name=%s : %s s",
                    api_key,
>                   kwargs["user_info"]["user_name"],
                    time.time() - start_time,
                )
E               KeyError: 'user_name'

../api/oauth.py:131: KeyError
```

Comment: The `kwargs["user_info"]` dictionary does not contain a key named "user_name".

Comment: @JohnGordon Sure, and what to do?

Comment: Either modify `kwargs["user_info"]` so that it _does_ have that key, or use some other key in that dict.

Comment: @JohnGordon I am worried about it, because it is the container which should run , successfully. Maybe it is issue with my pc?

Comment: You're setting `kwargs["user_info"] = users[0]` a few lines above where the error occurs, and users was the return value of `api_helpers.get_users_db_info({"user.api_key": f"$eq.{api_key}"})`, so the problem seems to be that the return of that function does not include the "user_name" key.  The problem is your database, not your container or PC